# Post checkbox data with ajax to java servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a script that i try to pass a check box value to ajax, somehow not able to.
To user, names will displayed, while i use the following  to get the IDlist for user selected names.

```
<script>
    var finalidlist = '';
        var checkboxes = $('.selectone');
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked === true) {
                if (finalidlist.length > 0) {
                    finalidlist += ',';
                }
                finalidlist += checkboxes[i].name;
            }
        }

    $('#selectall').click(function () {
        var checkboxes = $('.selectone');
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
        }
    });
    $('.selectone').click(function () {
    });
</script>
```

After that, i try to pass the values to ajax when user submit

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    $('#submit_button').click(function () { $.ajax({
                url: 'submit.jsp',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                async: false,
                data: {ids: finalidlist}
    }
   };
}

</script>
```

While i am not able to get the checked id list inside the ajax. I am pretty new to jsp, can anyone help on it?

Comment: might be that your ajax is in one script and your finalidlist is in another script

Comment: How does this issue have anything to do with posting to java? You are only addressing an issues with JavaScript not getting the required values. There is no issue in your question mentioned with the actual post.

Comment: your finalidlist is not updated on checkbox change

Comment: Thanks Andersen, u are rite..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved your script for initializing the finalidlist in the click handler. This way you don't need to update the list every time a checkbox changed.

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit_button').click(function () {
        var finalidlist = '';
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked === true) {
                if (finalidlist.length > 0) {
                    finalidlist += ',';
                }
                finalidlist += checkboxes[i].name;
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submit.jsp',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            data: {ids: finalidlist}
        }
    };
});
```